# SocketIO ReactJS - Not Receiving From Server Side

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, socket.io

Not sure why it does not work on my client side.
I already tried to remove the React.StrictMode and remove the disconnect.
But still cannot received any message.
I can emit the message to the Server Side, but cannot received anything from server side.
I have two server, 1 act as RestAPI and another as SocketIO.
Both of my server can communicate well through socketIO.
But not my client side.
Anything I am doing wrong?

**Client Side**

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const socket = io('http://localhost:8128');

        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('connect');
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log('disconnect');
        });

        socket.on('abc', (data) => {
            console.log(data);
        });

        return () => {};
    }, []);
```

**Server Side** (SocketIO Server)

```
  const httpServer = createServer(app);
  const io = new Server(httpServer, {
    cors: {
      origin: "*",
      methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    },
  });

  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("connection", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    socket.onAny((key, data) => {
      console.log(key, data);
    });
    socket.on("abc", (key, data) => {
      console.log(key, data);
    });
  });
  httpServer.listen(8128);
```

**Server Side Emitting** (Second Server)

```
  const socketIOClient = initSocketIOClient("http://localhost:8128");
  socketIOClient.emit("abc", "asd");
```

I already tried to remove the React.StrictMode and remove the disconnect from the return in useEffect. Still not working.

I just wanted to received the message in console.log().

Answer (score 0):

`Server Side Emitting` and `Client Side` are acting like clients.
`Server Side` is your server.

Your server (`Server Side`) must forward received message from `Server Side Emitting` to `Client Side`.

Here is the flow of messages:

> `Server Side Emitting` --> `Server Side` --> `Client Side`.

So your server just must emit the received message to the same channel.

What I added in `Server Side`

```
io.emit('abc', data)
```

##### Final code in Server Side

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('abc', (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        io.emit('abc', data)
    });
});
```